# Create automatic path layer for deriving digital elevation model using GoogleEarth and QGIS

Tags: qgis, google-earth

I recently found this post to create a digital elevation model (DEM) with Google Earth and QGIS. First it requires to manually create a path for sampling elevation data: 
http://monde-geospatial.com/create-contours-and-dem-using-google-earth-and-qgis-2-10/
While this works fine for smaller study regions, it its much of work for a large area to get enough sampling points, which are regularly distributed over the whole area (e.g. a point every 30m). Is there a way to create such a layer automatically and regularly (e.g. by predefining point distance)?

Comment: I admit, there is no convenient tool to get hight data for a custom region with QGIS so far. Recently I launched this question (https://www.mail-archive.com/qgis-user@lists.osgeo.org/msg31733.html)  on the mailing list, and the result was, that there is a need for a general framework for loading such data -> no short-term action on this. But your approach sounds really over-complicated. Better download SRTM data from the website and crop them to your needed region.

Comment: I can only suggest that you either use ASTER GDEM or SRTM, instead of trying to create a backdoor approach to getting access to the data that Google has. Besides, Google is likely using some kind of mix between ASTER GDEM, SRTM and local stuff.

Comment: Thank you. The datasets you mentioned are good enough for most of my applications.